# Installing Ruby through RVM on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

I can't seem to get Ruby installed on my Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS machine. I tried several different tutorials, and none of them worked. It seems like I can install RVM correctly using the command `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`. I do get this warning, though:

```
  * WARNING: Your '/root/.bashrc' contains `PATH=` with no `$PATH` inside, this can breakRVM,
  for details check https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525
  to avoid this warning append #PATH.
```

When I try to run `rvm install 1.9.3` I get the following and ruby doesn't install.

```
  Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
  If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.

  There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I tried adding `--verify-downloads 2`, but that also didn't work.

I eventually want to install rails but, of course need to install ruby first.

**Edit:**
I also get `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 170: cd: /path/to/tarballs/: No such file or directory` when trying to install ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not work as root, this is insecure and you can easily get bitten by it, start using user accounts for work/deployment. You can remove the current installation with:

   ```
   rm -rf /usr/local/rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
   ```
2. The warning you get happens because in `/root/.bashrc` there is `PATH=...` it is intended to be there, you should just not use root account directly (look 1.)
3. The checksums problems: it was caused by manually downloaded/build ruby archive, rvm will prevent those unless you specify the flag (`--verify-downloads 2`) which means you trust the archive with not matching checksum.
4. For the `cd` issue: you have a file `/etc/rvmrc` or `/root/.rvmrc` which specifies `rvm_archives_path=/path/to/tarballs` - make sure to remove it (it could be gone already after 1.).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed the step of adding the path to your `rvm/bin` directory in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.  Either one will work, here I'm using `~/.bashrc`.  Add the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` and reload `~/.bashrc` then give it a try.

```
# .bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin # This is default path
```

To reload your `~/.bashrc`

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I still get the same error. I also edited my question with more info if you'd like to take a look.